# Ninject mvc3 could not load WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute from assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I'm using ninject for mvc3 with an asp.net mvc 3 application. When I try to run the application, I get this error. I closed the cassini server and ran the vs-debugger again and the error still persisted. It was working before, it happened previously, but I have no idea how it started working again. I'm not sure if this is random or what.

What I know happened was that I hibernated the pc and woke it back up and tried to reload the website when I got that error. I haven't restarted my PC yet.

Error:

`Could not load type 'WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute' from assembly 'WebActivator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

I see this in visual studio:

```
Locating source for 'D:\Code\Bitbucket\WebActivator\WebActivator\PreApplicationStartCode.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {ca d6 fb 32 7f 34 6 22 5d 1f 1a 40 37 e8 da 47}
The file 'D:\Code\Bitbucket\WebActivator\WebActivator\PreApplicationStartCode.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'D:\Code\Bitbucket\WebActivator\WebActivator\PreApplicationStartCode.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'D:\Code\Bitbucket\WebActivator\WebActivator\PreApplicationStartCode.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: D:\Code\Bitbucket\WebActivator\WebActivator\PreApplicationStartCode.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'D:\Code\Bitbucket\WebActivator\WebActivator\PreApplicationStartCode.cs'.
```

Answer (score 9):

You have deployed the wrong version of WebActivator. Version 1.4 is required

Comment: The dll in the reference folder says: `Version: 1.4.1.0`

Comment: What's in the reference folder is not relevant. The question is what is deployed/loaded. Use Fusion log to check what is loaded and change it to the correct version.

Comment: You could try to check what versions are in your packages folder, I removed the old versions and rebuild the solution. It caused some build errors, and after adding a reference to the latest version of WebActivator it started working again. It seems to be caused by references to different versions of WebActivator.